# A new usage of として?

Tags: grammar

> 「始原の精霊を殺す......か。でも、始原の精霊の力を知りたがったのはわかる**として**、この世界に現れた位置と日時まで知りたがったっていうのは......」(Date
> a live, novel)

Context: the speaker was informed that 狂三 wanted to know the power of 始原の精霊, as well as the location and date of its first appearance in this world. Then, with this knowledge, 狂三 meant to kill 始原の精霊.

As far as I know, として derived from とする has two usages:

1. used to make an assumption or hypothesis
2. means "regard", "to consider ~" or "to view ~ as ~"

But these two usages don't appear to fit in this sentence.
(The speaker already knew the purpose of 狂三 so it makes no sense to hypothesize or consider the speaker knew that)
So how should I understand the として in this context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This ～として roughly means "Let me regard/assume/conclude/say ～ (and put it aside for now)". This is a set phrase used to make a comment/conclusion on a less important issue before talking about something more important.

> それはいいとして、宿題はやったの？
> That's fine, but (let's put that aside,) did you do your homework?
>
> お金はあるとして、PS5本体がどこにも売ってない。
> Granted, I have the money, but I can't find a PS5 console anywhere.
>
> それは明日考えるとして、とりあえず今日は寝よう。
> I'll think about it tomorrow, but for now, I'm going to sleep.
>
> 彼女は大丈夫だとして……。
> She will be okay for sure, but...
> <sub>(implies the speaker is concerned about someone else)</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much. But I can’t mentally connect “regard” with “put it aside for now” properly so I might as well consider it a new usage. And I just found another example「ま、まあその話は置いておくとして、です」. Is this として also the “put it aside for now” usage?

Comment: @chinoalpha Yes. として leads to something more important, but I'm not saying として literally means "put aside for now" per se, so it's not redundant.

Comment: @naruto, Since you ask in your profile for us to correct your already excellent English, you should know that your last line should be "concerned for" or "concerned about". Using "concerned with" implies that something is not pressing or important, and often implies romantic interest, and "concerned for" is used in situations regarding money, security, safety, or sufficiency.

Comment: @Ragaroni Thank you, I had checked the third meaning [here](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=concerned%20with&ref=sa), but this seems to be not as common as I thought.